# How to hinder root from running a script

Tags: bash, root, account-restrictions

The [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) application server provides scripts to administer the application server and also start and stop them and I would like to restrict the root user from running this script. The reason is that some key developers forget to administer the server as the non-privileged user and if they restart the application server as the root user, then the application server has to run by the root user [*].

It isn't an option to avoid giving root access and the developers forget because they are so used to do this on their local machine. I would like the `asadmin` script to either change to run as the non privileged user or optionally display an error message each time the script is run by root.

Bash shell is used.

[*]: I've tried to fix the rights on files, but even though I've tracked down lots of files which root owns and chmod them, the application experience strange errors and I have to run as root again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Similar to the other answers, but in the direction you wanted.

```
if [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "This script must NOT be run as root" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Alternatively, you can use `sudo` within the script to force execution as the non-privileged user using the `-u` flag to specify the user to run as. I don't use Glassfish, but here's a proto-example pseudo script.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 == "start" ]; then
  sudo -u nobody /usr/bin/glassfish
fi
```

Hopefully you get the idea. Sorry I don't really know what the script looks like, or the name of the non-privileged user.

Answer (score 3):

@Tshepang has the right idea. I don't know which is most portable, but here are other ways to detect whether the user is root:

```
id -u
$UID
```

Alternatively, you can simply force it to run as another user with the same parameters:

```
if [[ "$USER" != appuser ]]
then
    exec sudo -u appuser "$0" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: This is backward. He wants root to *not* run this script.

Comment: D'oh, forgot the `sudo` bit. Now it should do the job.

Comment: @TobySpeight No, the script does *nothing* if the user is root, as intended. I believe your change also results in an extra argument if `$@` is empty, and I've changed it to use a pattern found elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight, amended. I was sure I'd seen that form somewhere as a way to make sure zero arguments are passed correctly. Also fixed the check, which definitely had a bug (it wasn't a fork bomb, but would simply call itself indefinitely.

Comment: I'd argue it was a fork bomb, because each instance would fork a new shell for the `sudo` (it's not using `exec`) and the parent would wait for it, so you would eventually end up with a full process table.  It's still worth putting `exec` in there (if you don't intend the code after `fi` to run as the wrong user).

Comment: Good point about `exec`; fixed.